# Magento 2 Testing credit card working with Live credential of Authorize.net

Tags: magento2.3, authorize.net

I have the setup Live credential of Authorize.net 
I have also configured the production mode and Authorized and capture.

But when I am entering the testing credit card detail it is working.
Please help me why this happened?

Comment: Did you selected **Test Mode : Yes** in configuration ?

Comment: Currently set Test Mode : No

Comment: Disable test mode from autorize.net configuration and from magento configuration.
Secondly, flush cache and run. Do one more thind, check your authrorize.net account, it may be sandbox account or developer account.

Comment: Already test mode Disable but when i place order with testing card detail. it's not displaying restriction and place the order directly and then i have checked on the Live account there are displaying the on Unsetteled transaction report.

Comment: @KarangarMeghnathi, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @PushpendraSingh Nope, I have created a new account and configured it. But same problem i am facing

Comment: @KarangarMeghnathi, Please try this https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/dd7cb583b112f82ba58ef87d612631ac0eb1c57c

I did the same and it's working fine.